# Density of bridges for critical random regular graph

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs

Let $G_{n,d}$ be the space of all $d$-regular graphs with $n$ vertices. Now choose a graph from $G_{n,d}$ uniform at random. Once obtained do independent bond-percolation on it, i.e. keep an edge with probability $p$ and discard it with prob. $1-p$. It is known that this model has a critical point at $p_c = 1/(d-1)$. An interesting question is what is the average number of bridges or better the average density of bridges for $n\rightarrow \infty$. My numerical analysis suggests it is exactly $p_c$ for $n\rightarrow \infty$. That is what remains is a forest. How would one show this rigorously? Is the configuration model of use?

Comment: I have been able to translate the problem of calculating the density of bridges for fixed $n$ and $d$ to the calculation of the following covariance, i.e. $\mathbb{E}[K\mathcal{N}] - \mathbb{E}[K]\mathbb{E}[\mathcal{N}]$ at the desired bond-density $p_c$. Here $K$ is the number of components and $\mathcal{N}$ is the density of edges, i.e. the number of active edges divided by nd/2. That gives one a different point of view on the problem...